# What's the difference between the 95% confidence interval and the 95% in the 68-95-99 rule?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

What's the difference between the 95% confidence interval and 95% in the 68-95-99 rule?

Answer (score 0):

The [Empirical Rule](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/2/2.2/2.2.7) is a phenomenon of normal distributions. Given normally distributed observations the two are interchangeable.

[image]

However a [Confidence Interval](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/4/4.2) can also be applied to data that is [Non-Normally](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/node/261/) distributed.